# How to write a function that calls function from the library?

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to write some program to display telemetry data on charts using Processing IDE. I use ControlP5 library to create chart. There will be many of them so I wanted to write some function that generates them, but there is some problem, I am not sure how to send chart name to the function. I tried using *this* but  IDE throws some error:

> The function create_chart(String, int, int, int, int, int, String) does not exist.

Here is code that I use:

```
ControlP5 gui;
Chart dane;

int i = 0, minimum, maximum;
int zero_point;
void setup()
{

  size(1280, 720);
  smooth();
  gui= new ControlP5(this);
 
  PFont pfont = createFont("TIMES", 20, true); // use true/false for smooth/no-smooth
  ControlFont font = new ControlFont(pfont, 30);
  gui.setFont(font);
  dane.create_chart("Dane", 0, 450, 300, 415, 210, "world");
  
  delay(100);
}



void draw()
{
  textSize(15);
  i=i+(int(random(-50, 50)));
  background(45);/*
  dane.push("zero", 0);
  dane.push("world", i);
  minimum = int(min(dane.getValuesFrom("world")));
  maximum = int(max(dane.getValuesFrom("world")));
  if (maximum<0) maximum = 0;
  if (minimum>0) minimum = 0;
  dane.setRange(minimum, maximum);
  text(maximum, 390, 220);
  text(minimum, 390, 510);
  if (minimum<=0 && minimum!=maximum) {
    zero_point = 220 + 290*maximum/(maximum-minimum);
    text(0, 390, zero_point);
  }
  dane.getValueLabel();*/
}


class Dane {

  Dane dane = new Dane();
}
public void create_chart(String name, int chart_number, int size_x, int size_y, int position_x, int position_y, String data)
  {

    gui.printPublicMethodsFor(Chart.class);
    dane = gui.addChart(name)
      .setPosition(position_x, position_y)
      .setSize(size_x, size_y)
      .setRange(-20, 20)
      .setView(Chart.LINE)
      ;
    this.getColor().setBackground(color(100, 100));
    this.addDataSet("zero");
    this.setData("zero", new float[500]);
    this.addDataSet("world");
    this.setColors("world", color(100, 100, 500));
    this.setStrokeWeight(3);
  }
```

Comment: `create_chart` is not defined within the class definition of `Dane` as posted so therefore it does not exist as used.

Comment: Also your definition of `Dane` seems to introduce an infinite constructor `<init>` sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Andy the `create_chart` method is not defined within the `Dane` class in the above code example. This should be fixed first.

If you didn’t intend to add `create_chart` to a separate class, you might want to change

```
dane.create_chart(…);
```

to simply

```
create_chart(…);
```

This however renders the `Dane` class (even more) useless.

Otherwise in your code `dane` in the `setup()` method is an instance of `Chart` from the ControlP5 library. The `Chart` class doesn’t seem to have any `create_chart` method and you probably intended to call the method from your `Dane` class.

So you probably want to change the type of `dane` from `Chart` to `Dane`.

The `Dane` class itself seems to have some issues as well (what’s the purpose of the `dane` member? And `ControlP5.addChart` returns `Chart` and not `Dane`) but this is out-of-scope for this question.

All in all your code has several issues that make it difficult to guess what your expectations are and how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I use 'Dane' class because I want to create many charts just simply using 'dane.create_chart(…);' and just change word before come as a name of chart. I'm not sure if that makes sens, I'm just starting using Processing.

Comment: You don’t need a separate class for this. Simply use `create_chart` as local instance method.